# Transparent speedbutton mouse hover

Tags: windows, delphi, background

I have a very annoying problem, when the transparent property of the form is true and when I go with the mouse over the SpeedButton flat, appears the screen background, it seems that the button will update slowly, If you do not understand, I can make a video. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about how you are doing this?  Code?  Are you using the `TransparentColor` property of the form? Which version of Delphi?  Themes?

Comment: yes, transparentcolor property, I have Delphi 2010 and use regular themes.

Answer (score 2):

Flat SpeedButton are tricky beasts. They are supposed to be transparent except for their caption and/or glyph until they are "activated" by a mouse over or clicked.

Now, if you turn the form transparent, because they get the form background color, they become also "windows transparent" and do not respond to mouse event on their transparent parts (just like the form): if you click, you really click on what's behind.

Your problem is that now they do not get activated anymore by a mouse over unless you have your mouse exactly over the caption or the glyph.

One workaround would be to have your SpeedButtons almost covered by the glyph and the caption.

Note: the transparency associated with "Flat" works differently if the SpeedButtons are Transparent themselves. In that case they show whatever is in the background (shapes, images) while regular ones show only the parent background color...